# How to Build a Guess the the Line Interactive Plot in RShiny?

Tags: shiny, visualization, interactive

I am attempting to build a visualization similar to that of the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/01/15/us/politics/you-draw-obama-legacy.html), in their article "You Draw It: What Got Better or Worse During Obama’s Presidency". I am primarily versed in R and Python and have attempted to build this in RShiny but am not satisfied with the outcome. Can anyone point me to code similar to used for the NYT visualization (likely using Java) or how to code a visualization similar to this in R?

Here is the current code I am building:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Click on the plot to start drawing, click again to pause"),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
  actionButton("calculate", "Calculate Difference"),
  plotOutput("plot", width = "600px", height = "500px",
             hover = hoverOpts(id = "hover", delay = 100, delayType = "throttle", clip = TRUE, nullOutside = TRUE),
             click = "click"),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.calculate > 0",
    textOutput("difference_text")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  vals <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL, last_x = NULL)
  draw <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  base_line_intervals <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  baseline_alpha <- reactiveVal(0.0) 
  
  base_line <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014),
      value = c(10, 20, 50, 22, 50)
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    base_line_intervals(base_line()$year[2] - base_line()$year[1])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$click, handlerExpr = {
    temp <- draw()
    
    if (is.null(vals$last_x) && is.null(vals$x)) {
      vals$x <- c(vals$x, base_line()$year[3])
      vals$y <- c(vals$y, base_line()$value[3])
    }
    
    draw(!temp)
    
    if (!draw()) {
      vals$x <- c(vals$x, NA)
      vals$y <- c(vals$y, NA)
    } else {
      vals$last_x <- NULL
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, handlerExpr = {
    vals$x <- NULL
    vals$y <- NULL
    vals$last_x <- NULL
    baseline_alpha(0.0) 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$calculate, handlerExpr = {
    baseline_alpha(0.8)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$hover, {
    if (draw()) {
      if (is.null(vals$last_x) || input$hover$x > (vals$last_x + base_line_intervals())) {
        adjusted_x <- floor(input$hover$x / base_line_intervals()) * base_line_intervals()
                if (!is.null(vals$last_x) && adjusted_x == vals$last_x) {
          return(NULL)
        }
        
        vals$x <- c(vals$x, adjusted_x)
        vals$y <- c(vals$y, input$hover$y)
        vals$last_x <- adjusted_x
      }
    }
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    drawn_line <- data.frame(x = vals$x, y = vals$y)
        plot(x = base_line()$year, y = base_line()$value, ylim = c(0, 60),
         ylab = "Value", xlab = "Year", type = "n")
        lines(x = base_line()$year[base_line()$year <= 2012], 
          y = base_line()$value[base_line()$year <= 2012], 
          lwd = 2, col = rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha = 0.8))
        lines(x = base_line()$year[base_line()$year >= 2012], 
          y = base_line()$value[base_line()$year >= 2012], 
          lwd = 2, col = rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha = baseline_alpha()))
        lines(x = drawn_line$x[drawn_line$x >= 2012], 
          y = drawn_line$y[drawn_line$x >= 2012], 
          col = "red", lty = 2, lwd = 2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```